# Is there a way to make a scrolling "viewport" box in HTML5/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider i have a div with content in it, but i only want to show a part of it. Specifically the part that overlaps with another div. How would I go about making that happen?

I also want to animate my content div so that it's actually scrolling, whilst the smaller div acts as a "window" or "viewport" to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/27bxx/

The div will scroll as soon as it is loaded

Comment: this is perfect, thanks. the other method i was looking at is to use the property to define a mask but yours is obviously better.

Comment: Glad I could help. What property/mask do you mean? I'm always interested in finding alternative ways to do things.

Comment: the css "clip" property, as mentioned in this tutorial: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-simple-but-useful-css-properties -clip: rect(top right bottom left);

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: scroll;`

And then just constraint the width/height.